# How to upload file in rest api Codeigniter

Tags: rest, codeigniter

I am stuck in uploading file in rest api in codeigniter. continously am getting the error. You do not select a file to upload[image]

```
    $config['upload_path'] = $url.'public/images/users_pictures/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size']      = '10096000';
        $config['max_height'] = '3648';
        $config['max_width'] = '6724';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
        {
        // $this->upload->do_upload('cover');
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
        $this->db->set(array('user_image' => $picture));
        $this->db->where('user_id',$uid);
        $update = $this->db->update('asm_register');
        return $update;
        }
      else
      {
          echo $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
          return "";

      }
```

Comment: it means `print_r($_FILES)`  is unpopulated. the issue is elsewhere in your code. how are you uploading?

Comment: I think the issue is in the form-submitting methods. when i switched to multipart/form-data then it's not evening picking the field value. what should i use instead?

Comment: i don't know, i can't see that code

Comment: Fine bro. let me show you in detail

Answer (score 1):

**Answer** - Remove the `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` and leave that empty.

While doing on api you have to play around with file handelings.

Created a method called file_upload_check to check file, you just need to pass a file input name as parameter.

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Here $image_name is the name attibute of html tag.

```
function file_upload_check($image_name)
{
    if (isset($_FILES[$image_name]["tmp_name"]) AND  $_FILES[$image_name]['name']!="") {
        $check_image = getimagesize($_FILES[$image_name]["tmp_name"]);
        $filename   = $_FILES[$image_name]["tmp_name"];
        $handle     = fopen($filename, "r");
        $get_name   = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

        if ($check_image == false) {
            $data['error'] = '<p class="text-danger">The file you have selected is not an image.</p>';
            $data['err'] = 1;
        }else{

            // You file upload code placed here



            $data['file_name'] = $get_name;
            $data['err'] = 0;
        }
    }else{
        $data['error'] = '<p class="text-danger">Please select a file to upload.</p>';
        $data['err'] = 1;
    }

    return $data;
}



function get_file_name()
{
    // this parameter is input file name that i am passing as a parameter.
    $fileData = $this->file_upload_check('file');

    if ($fileData['err'] == 0) {

        // Here is your file name

        $file_name = $fileData['file_name'];
    }else{
        $error = $fileData['error'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did i get that $image_name variable from? that you passed in the function

Comment: I got the same issue bro ... <p class="text-danger">Please select a file to upload.</p>

Comment: I told you i didn't able to get the file to be selected ... can you explain this issue?

Comment: Now i get the point , you see the headers tab in postman you need to set the `Content-Type : multipart/form-data`

Comment: Have u tried to remove the `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` and leave that empty..?

Comment: https://developer.esignlive.com/forums/topic/upload-a-new-document-through-multipartform-data-using-postman/

Comment: It work bro. while removing the Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this one.

```
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file_name'))
    {
    // $this->upload->do_upload('cover');
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
    $this->db->set(array('user_image' => $picture));
    $this->db->where('user_id',$uid);
    $update = $this->db->update('asm_register');
    return $update;
    }
```